# Select rows for a specific date using TIMESTAMP datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have the tables below in my database:

```
Student    (Stud_no: string, Stud_name: string)
Membership (Mem_no: string, Stud_no: string)
Book       (book_no: string, book_name: string, author: string)
Iss_rec    (iss_no: integer, iss_date: date, Mem_no: string, book_no: string)
```

I created the tables and inserted values defined by the above schemas. I used **TIMESTAMP** in the *iss_date* so that present date is taken by the system automatically as the default value for *iss_date*.

Now I have to **List all the student and Book name, Author issued on a specific date (e.g., 06-08-2019)**.

I wrote this query:

```sql
SELECT student.stud_name, book.book_name, book.author,iss_rec.iss_date
FROM student, book, iss_rec, membership
WHERE student.stud_no = membership.stud_no
AND membership.Mem_no = iss_rec.Mem_no
AND book.book_no = iss_rec.book_no
AND iss_date = '2019-08-06'
```

but it yields nothing! Whenever I cut off the last line: `AND iss_date = '2019-08-06'`, it yields a list. But how could I get list for a specific date as I mentioned earlier? **I don't want hour:minute:second, only yyyy-mm-dd.**

Comment: In MySQL 8 you can specify a default value for datetime column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATE` function

```
AND DATE(iss_date) = '2019-08-06';
```

Comment: Note that other answers either omit functions altogether, or attach them to the constant, and not the indexed data. It's much more efficient that way.

Answer (score 2):

Just write you query as:

```
AND iss_date >= '2019-08-06'
AND iss_date <  '2019-08-07'
```

Or more conveniently:

```
AND iss_date >= '2019-08-06'
AND iss_date <  '2019-08-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

While this looks lengthy, it can use indexes more efficiently and very generic.

Comment: Yes, or `BETWEEN '2019-08-06 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-06 23:59:59'`

Comment: @Strawberry that would become dependent on the datatype e.g. if it is DATETIME(6) then you need `BETWEEN '2019-08-06 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-06 23:59:59.999999'`.

Comment: :-) Yep. Every second counts!

Answer (score 0):

Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. Join us.

FWIW, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT s.stud_name
     , b.book_name
     , b.author
     , r.iss_date
  FROM student s
  JOIN membership m
    ON m.stud_no = s.stud_no 
  JOIN iss_rec r 
    ON r.Mem_no = m.Mem_no 
  JOIN book b
    ON b.book_no = r.book_no
 WHERE r.iss_date BETWEEN '2019-08-06 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-06 23:59:59';
```